# yii2 rest - using PUT to update data

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-api

I am using a REST API in `Yii2 with Authorization Bearer` 
I have configured the actionUpdate completely but somehow when using PUT to update the data, I am getting null value when I try to get the post data,

```
print_r($request->getBodyParam('member_id'))
```

Get below result when `print_r(Yii::$app->request->bodyParams):`

`Content -type is multipart/form-data`

> Array
>   (
>       [------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "member_id" 
>   274505
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="claim_type"
>   3
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="visit_date"
>   2016-10-12
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="provider_id"
>   0
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="diagnosis"
>   fevercc
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reimbursement"
>   1
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="non_panel"
>   true
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="provider_name"
>   klinik abc
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reimbursement_reason"
>   near to house
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="invoice_no"
>   1245
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="medical_leave"
>   0
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="leave_form"
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="amount_incurred" 24
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryAF3YWAApi5BxYUb2--
>   )

Below is my actionUpdate

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {

    $claim = $this->findModel($id);
    $claim->scenario = 'update';

    if ( $claim->status_id == 1 ) {

        $request = Yii::$app->request;

            if (isset($request)) {

                $member_id  = $request->getBodyParam('member_id');
                $claim_type = $request->getBodyParam('claim_type');
                $visit_date = $request->getBodyParam('visit_date');
                $provider_id = $request->getBodyParam('provider_id');
                $diagnosis = $request->getBodyParam('diagnosis');
                $reimbursement = $request->getBodyParam('reimbursement');

                $userlogin_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

                if ($claim->validate() ) {       
                    $claim->save();                             
                    return array('id'=>$claim->id,'msg'=>'Successfully update claim');

                } else {
                    return (ActiveForm::validate($claim));
                }
            }
    } else {
        throw new \yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException('You are not allowed to update data');
    }
}
```

Comment: To treat a PUT/DELETE request body as form-urlencoded data, you can read php://input and parse it using parse_str. See for example http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php.

Comment: It's working if I use body as form-urlencoded data but I want to use multipart/form-data because I need to upload some files - @Refilon

Comment: I believe that uploading a file together with form data (ie multi-part)  is not allowed when using PUT, only for POST. Check out the specs for HTTP.